# OpenAPI 3.0 Specification Extensions with PHP Attributes

Tags: php, swagger, openapi

I am programming an API with the Open API 3.0 Scheme and Swagger.
According to [swagger specification](https://swagger.io/specification/#specification-extensions) one is allowed to add custom properties named like x-...

I am using PHP Attributes, example:

```php
    #[OA\Get(
      path: "/test_api",
      tags: ["Test"],
      operationId: "my_function",
      summary: "Hello Stackoverflow",
      x-custom: "test"
  )]
```

As you can see, I am trying to add a custom propertie like x-custom. But PHP Attributes does not allow naming variables with a - .

Does anyone have an Idea, how i can add any custom property?

If i just add xCustom for example, the api will fail to execute using the swagger php library.

Comment: Have you tried underscore instead of hyphen?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution [here](https://zircote.github.io/swagger-php/reference/attributes.html)

```php
#[OA\Get(
      path: "/test_api",
      tags: ["Test"],
      operationId: "my_function",
      summary: "Hello Stackoverflow",
      x: ["custom"=>"test"]
  )]
```

When working with it, one can access it like this:

```php
$api->x["custom"])
```